# how to create class that that has a list in it, and the list should contain two different kind of objects

Tags: java

For example:

I have two type of objects:

```
public class Image {
...
}
```

And

```
public class Video {
...
}
```

I want to have a class that will contain a single list of those two objects, like this:

```
public class Media {

private List<Object> mediaList = new....
....
}
```

Comment: You might make media the parent class to Image and Video and then you could make a container class that has a List<Media> collection in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a parent class, and have Image and Video be children of it.

You can then make the list of the parent type.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example
{
    public abstract ImageVideo
    {

    }

    public class Image extends ImageVideo
    {

    }

    public class Video extends ImageVideo
    {

    }

    public static class Media
    {
        public static void main( String args[] )
        {
            Image image = new Example().new Image();
            Video video = new Example().new Video();

            List<ImageVideo> mediaList = new ArrayList<ImageVideo>();

            mediaList.add( image );
            mediaList.add( video );
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the following compiles, you would just have to cast the objects back when you retrieve them from the list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example
{
    public class Image
    {

    }

    public class Video
    {

    }

    public static class Media
    {
        public static void main( String args[] )
        {
            Image image = new Example().new Image();
            Video video = new Example().new Video();

            List<Object> mediaList = new ArrayList<Object>();

            mediaList.add( image );
            mediaList.add( video );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: another option is creating an interface. `implents MediaType`.

Comment: thank you for very clear explanation. it worked like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent Class.

```
 public abstract Class MediaFormat{
}
```

and then the child classes

```
    public class Image extends MediaFormat{
...
}

    public class Video extends MediaFormat{
...
}
```

then finally

```
    public class Media {
     private List<MediaFormat> mediaList = new List<MediaFormat>();
     ...
}
```

The parent class (MediaFormat) is abstract.That way you make sure that MediaFormat cannot be instantiated.